# cent os is reinstalling during installation in virtual box

Tags: linux, installation, virtualbox, centos7, reboot

I am trying to install cent os on virtual box and when it shows "cent os is successfully installed and ready for you to use Go ahead and reboot to start using it"  and when i press  reboot, it again start for reinstalling all over again from start.
I tried almost 7-8 times and same thing is happening.

Comment: Eject the DVD (virtual or otherwise) before rebooting. It's probably restarting because that's what it's booting from.

Answer (score 1):

When you show "cent os is successfully installed and ready for you to use Go ahead and reboot to start using it" before reboot you need to do some steps...

1. go to 'devices' on virtual box.
2. tab called 'cd/dvd devices'
3. uncheck the option said 'cent_os.iso'.
4. pop up comes click 'force 
   mount'
   Then click reboot.
   Once you see black screen,
5. go to 'machine' and click 
   'reset'.
   [image]
   Now you can enjoy using cent os on virtual box.

Comment: Worst! Screenshot! Ever! :-) If you could make it a bit smaller, rotate it a quarter circle anti-clockwise, and bullet-point your answer, this would be perfect. But here's a vote for getting what's almost certainly the correct answer.